# Appending code/text in previous console output to display status

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, services

I have been unable to find out how this "code" below is created.

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
[ ok ] Restarting nmbd (via systemctl): nmbd.service.
[ ok ] Restarting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.service.
```

Specifically after calling the command, this is shown at first:

```
[ .. ] Restarting nmbd (via systemctl): nmbd.service.
```

Followed by a comfirmation of restart by the service, it changes to

```
[ ok ] Restarting nmbd (via systemctl): nmbd.service.
```

with the `..` changing to `ok`

I would like to incorporate these into my own scripts but haven't been able to find the code for these or any similar.

Help would be appreciated!

Please note, I am only using Samba as an example since this presents the output I am referring too.

*The only possibility, to my knowledge, is that it runs some for of python script, but going through the service file for any arbitary service that has a similar output has no mention of a python script nor something that echo's `ok`*

cat /etc/init.d/samba

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          samba
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: ensure Samba daemons are started (nmbd, smbd and samba)
# Description: Starts Samba, a Windows AD and SMB/CIFS fileserver for UNIX
### END INIT INFO

set -e

# start nmbd, smbd and samba-ad-dc unconditionally
# the init scripts themselves check if they are needed or not
case $1 in
    start)
        /etc/init.d/nmbd start
        /etc/init.d/smbd start
        /etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc start
        ;;
    stop)
        /etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc stop
        /etc/init.d/smbd stop
        /etc/init.d/nmbd stop
        ;;
    reload)
        /etc/init.d/smbd reload
        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
        /etc/init.d/nmbd "$1"
        /etc/init.d/smbd "$1"
        /etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc "$1"
        ;;
    status)
        status=0
        NMBD_DISABLED=`testparm -s --parameter-name='disable netbios' 2>/dev/null || true`
        SERVER_ROLE=`samba-tool testparm --parameter-name="server role"  2>/dev/null | tail -1 || true`
        if [ "$SERVER_ROLE" != "active directory domain controller" ]; then
            if [ "$NMBD_DISABLED" != "Yes" ]; then
                /etc/init.d/nmbd status || status=$?
            fi
            /etc/init.d/smbd status || status=$?
        else
            /etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc status || status=$?
        fi
        exit $status
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/samba {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**printf and overwriting with carriage return**

This type of "magic" can be done via `printf` and carriage return "\r" to overwrite existing output.  However, you will have to be conscious for consecutive lines. Observe this example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

string="[  ] pinging google.com "

printf "%s" "$string"

if ping -c 4 -q google.com > /dev/null 
then
    printf "\r[OK"
    printf "\n\n"
fi
```

Notice how we have the "status" string print first, then we use carriage return to jump back to the beginning and overwrite first 3 characters with "[OK" string. The following two newlines is just example of what you'd want to do to move the script onwards and print more lines. As for the `if command ; then . . . fi` , this is simple structure which executes body of if statement conditionally , depending on `command` output.

Disadvantage of this approach is that if you don't match the character lengths of what you're printing, then it might show through.

```
$ printf "Hello\rcat\n" 
catlo
```

**Slightly better approach: clearing the line with escape code**

We can take advantage of [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for clearing line (in this case, in octal `\033[2K` ) for getting rid of what we previously had on the line. This has advantage of not running out in the issue of matching/not-matching length of what you print when you reset the cursor back to the beginning.

Here's an example, with added UTF-8 characters for check and cross-mark

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

string="[ ] pinging google.com "
printf "%s" "$string"

if ping -c 4 -q google.com > /dev/null 
then
    # clear previous line, add UTF checkmar to string
    printf "\r%b" "\033[2K"
    string="[\U2713] pinging google.com "
else
    # clear previous line, add UTF checkmar to string
    printf "\r%b" "\033[2K"
    string="[\U274C] pinging google.com "
fi
printf "%b" "$string"
```

Comment: I should start using and reading printf docs more! thank you for the help! I guess the same applies for the 'apt-get' with its progress and update options? I would like to make use of these functions too

Comment: @Cybex  I don't know about `apt-get` since I've never read their source code. They might be doing something far more complex. The benefit of this approach is that it's simple and easy to understand.