# How to delete showing text in terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm doing a highschool project and I wanted to know how to delete showing text in the terminal.
**I don't know how I can show text, delete it and write some text above while the script is running, without any interaction of the user.** Obviusly I want this on a shell script and run it later. *Sorry if my English is so bad.*

Comment: Are you asking how to [Overwrite previous output in Bash instead of appending it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16149/overwrite-previous-output-in-bash-instead-of-appending-it) ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I dind't notice that post because I searched for an answer in many different ways and I didn't find it.