# How to create a rotation animation then replace it with some text then repeat it using Bash

Tags: bash, scripts

Sorry if the title isn't too descriptive. I want to achieve the following "animation":

```
- Song Name
\ Song Name    # all these 4 would stay on the same line by
| Song Name    # replacing each other every 0.5 seconds     
/ Song Name
current_window_title # then for 2 seconds the current window 
                     # title will be displayed

# repeat the animation from the start over and over
```

I hope that you understand. I'm trying to make a module for my Polybar that shows the played song, then shows the current window title. Unfortunately, I'm not that experienced with Bash in order to achieve this result.

So far I managed to get the song animation part, but when it comes to combining it with the 2 seconds of displaying the current window name on the same line, ahh kind of a headache.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

chars="/-\|"
while sleep 0.5; do
    echo -en "${chars:$(( i=(i+1) % ${#chars} )):1}" "Song Name" "\r"
done
```

Can you guys give me some pointers or some help please? Tried to do it myself for 2 days but I can't really figure it out. Is it possible at least?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

chars="/-\|"
while :; do
    for (( i=0; i<${#chars}; i++ )); do
        printf '%s %s\r' "${chars:$i:1}" "Song Name"
        sleep 0.5
    done
    # Clear line and print window name
    printf '\033[2K%s\r' "$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"
    sleep 2
    # Go up one line and clear line
    printf "\033[2K"

done
# Add newline in the very end if you like
echo
```

This is a combination of:

- [Is it possible to retrieve the active window process/title in Gnome?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38867/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-active-window-process-title-in-gnome)
- [How to delete line with echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26576/how-to-delete-line-with-echo)
- [Overwrite previous output in Bash instead of appending it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16149/overwrite-previous-output-in-bash-instead-of-appending-it)

You may need to install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Comment: Just as a side note: OP wants to use the script in polybar and "clearing" a line in polybar works a bit different than in the shell. In polybar each new line clears the previous one. So no carriage return or ANSI escape codes are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

chars="/-\|"

while sleep 0.5; do
    tput el
    echo -en "${chars:$(( i=(i+1) % ${#chars} )):1}" "Song Name" "\r"
    (($i == 3)) && sleep 0.5 && tput el && echo -en "$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)" "\r" && sleep 1.5     
done
```

- `tput el` clears the line for next output. Although you might not need it for Polybar... But it's there just in case.
- `(($i == 3))` when this condition is met, the commands after it on the same line separated by `&&` will run one after the other. `3` is how many characters in `chars="/-\|"` starting from 0 so `0,1,2,3`... Keep this in mind when changing the string in `chars`.

Notice that `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname` will get the current active window name... This means the active window at each time `"$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"` is run... which could be your browser tab for example if you click on it at that time. Unfortunately this behavior is the same with other tools like `xprop` and `wmctrl`... a workaround would be to declare a variable before the while loop like so `window="$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"` and `echo` this variable inside the loop so it remains the same afterwords avoiding other active windows later on... Or you can set a static name and `echo` it if you know the name in advance.